# Create dynamic collectionview in one viewcontroller

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

[image][image]"I am new one for iOS development now I am working on collection view. Whenever view appears I will load data with the given array, then if user did select the cell again I want to load different data again,  if there is no child in the array I want to load the previous data , these all should happen in one controller. The child data can be n number of data. i have a json like this"

func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return item.count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! ProofAddressCell
    cell.nameLabel.text = item[indexPath.row]["address_title"] as? String
    return cell
}
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

 if let childItem = item[indexPath.row]["child"] as? [[String: AnyObject]]  {
        if childItem.count > 1 {
        item = childItem
            let addItems: [[String: AnyObject]]!
           // addItems.append(item)
        collectionView.reloadData()
        }
        else {
             print("There is no option to show")
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Welcome", message: "No child available", preferredStyle: .alert)
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil))
            self.present(alert, animated: true, completion:{ () in

                self.moveBack()

            })
        }
    }
    else {
    print("There is no option to show")
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Welcome", message: "No child available", preferredStyle: .alert)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil))
    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion:{ () in

        self.moveBack()

    })
    }
}

func moveBack() {
    print("have to move back")
    //item = childArray
}
```

When view appears i loaded the data title and subtitle as "Home" and "Firm"
When home tapped i want to load "Home child 1" and "Home child 2" if user again clicks the "Home child 1" cell i want to load next child if child has value.

Please guide me how to implement this ?

Comment: Did you parse your JSON at least? Do you have UICollectionView Code at least? What's your exact issue? There are plenty of question on SO with answers, but you need to separate each step, and try it.

Comment: @Larme yes i have parsed the json. can you please provide any example for this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you want to use Decoder

```
struct Root: Codable {
    let captureMethod, addressTitle, addressSubtitle: String
    let addressRequired: Int
    let poafilename: String
    let child: [Root]
}

let decoder =  JSONDecoder() 
decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
let res = decoder.decode(Root.self,from:data)
item.append(res)
```

Second you need to keep a stack of previous path

```
var myStack = [[Root]]()
var item = [Root]()


if item[indexPath.row].child.count > 1  {
  myStack.append(item)
  item = item[indexPath.row].child
}
else {
  print("No more childs")
}
```

When you want to move back

```
if let las = myStack.last  {
  myStack = Array(myStack.dropLast())
  item = las
}
else {
  print("No more prevs")
}
```